# Any way to count High Volume Platform Events published by Event type? What happens when exceeded?

Tags: limits, platform-event

I'm familiar with the Limits API value `HourlyPublishedPlatformEvents` for the total HV events published in the last 60 minutes, as well as the `PlatformEventUsageMetric` object for querying total events published (or delivered via CometD) for a 24 hour period.  Is there any way to see the number of events published *by event type* in a 1 hour or 24 hour period?  We are unexpectedly hitting our limits, and need to track down the source of the events.  We have a number of event types defined; narrowing down the issue to a single (or handful of) platform event(s) would be very helpful.

Also, when publishing these events, what happens when the limit is exceeded?  Are the events simply dropped, or or they enqueued to publish later?  I would assume as it is a publish limit, they would be dropped, but the continual high rate of consumption has made me question if they are just piling up.

Comment: I was also wondering how to get more granular reporting from PlatformEventUsageMetric...